# Remove element from vector of maps

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of maps:

```
typedef map<string, string> aMap;
typedef vector<aMap> rVec;
rVec rows;
```

How can I remove some elements from rows?

The following code does not work.

```
struct remove_it
{
  bool operator() (rVec& rows)
  {
    // Validation code here!

  }
};

rVec::iterator it = remove(rows.begin(), rows.end(), remove_it());
rows.erase(it, rows.end());
```

I got the following error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'remove(std::vector<s
td::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator, std::vec
tor<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator, mai
n(int, char**)::remove_it)'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your error message is truncated.

Comment: What do you expect `remove(...)` to do?

Comment: I would like to remove some elements from the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First off: please provide a single compilable example.
Your code posted above is problematic as rVec and rowsVector have been interchanged (you would have seen that yourself if you had posted real code).

2) You are using the wrong remove. It should be remove_if

3) It is normal for the functor to be const

4) The operator() should get object of type aMap (as that is what is in your vector) not a reference back to the vector.

5) Don't be lazy add std:: in-front of objects in the standard namespace.
rather than using `using namespace std;`

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> aMap;
typedef std::vector<aMap>        rVec;

rVec rows;

struct remove_it
{
                 // Corrected type here
  bool operator() (aMap const& row) const  // const here
  {
    // Validation code here!
    return true;
  }
};

int main()
{
                                 // _if herer
    rVec::iterator it = std::remove_if(rows.begin(), rows.end(), remove_it());
    rows.erase(it, rows.end());
}
```

Comment: I still get "error: no matching function for call to remove_if ..." error.

Comment: @Selinap: Copy and paste the above code into a source file and compile. It compiles with no errors. But it is hard to debug your code without your actual code. See Point 1 above. **Post compilable code.**

Comment: PS. You are probably missing (std::) or forgetting to include <algorithm>

Comment: @Martin: Is it possible to include an argument in remove_it? For example, remove_it(var).

Answer (score 1):

[`remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) expects a value.  You are trying to use a functor, you need to use [`remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) for that.

Also, your functor needs to accept an object of type aMap, not rVec.

Comment: Changing to remove_if gave "error: no matching function for call to 
remove_if(__gnu_cxx...".

Comment: @Selinap:  Which gives us very little useful information.  Post a complete error message, and the code that gave it.

Answer (score 0):

[`remove_if`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/algorithm/remove_if) is what you want, not [`remove`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/algorithm/remove).